# php insert to sql not working

Tags: php, sql, apache, ubuntu

I'm on ubuntu running on apache2.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "loops");
if (!mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error to connect: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
echo "First: ".$firstName."<br />Age: ".$age;

$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
values (".$firstName.",".$lastName.",".$age.")";

if (!mysqli_query($con)) {
    die("Error :".mysqli_error($con);
}
echo "1 added";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I don't know what to do now, but the error seems to be on the '$sql', 'cause when I put that 
under a comment, the rest works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the infamous mistake of wrapping the `varchar` variables with single quote '

```
"INSERT INTO persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
values ('".$firstName."','".$lastName."','".$age."')";
```

**Additionally**, It's highly risky for you, not be using protections against [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but not on the database. I created a table like this:              $sql = "CREATE TABLE persons (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(ID), FirstName CHAR(30), SecondName CHAR(30), Age INT)";

Comment: @user3160582, If your table column for `age` is int and not `varchar` than you should remove the wrapping of single quote from only `$age`.

Comment: I've changed it, created another table, but still does not save on it.

Comment: @user3160582, Could you change `if (!mysqli_query($con)) { die("Error :".mysqli_error($con); }` to this `mysqli_query($con) or die("Error :".mysql_error());` and tell us what the error ?

Comment: I've done that before, but it was just superficial. I've done it from the begining now, created another table, now with varchar on it, and changed to "if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))" and now it finally worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  `mysqli_query($con, $sql)` You need to execute the query so that it will store into the database

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
        values ('".$firstName."','".$lastName."','".$age."')";
 if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
       ...................^
    die("Error :".mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Comment: @user3160582, I already mentioned the same in my answer!! But I dont know, why you have not looked into that :)

Comment: But I tried that and didn't worked at first, but when I did all again it worked. Thank you too.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age`) values (".$firstName.",".$lastName.",".$age.")";
```

If this doesn't work, what error do you get.

Comment: The problem doesn't lies inside the "Reserve" column names, therefor wrapping them with ` won't solve this issue.